# Starting PowerMTA: [FAILED] Centos6

Tags: linux, vps, centos6, pmta

Have recently installed PowerMTA server on CentOS 6,  but unable to start pmta service and getting this error in logs.

```
service pmta restart
```

> Stopping PowerMTA:                                         [  OK  ]
>   Starting PowerMTA:                                         [FAILED]

```
/usr/sbin/pmtad --debug
```

> 2018-05-26 20:41:27 WARNING (line 15 of /etc/pmta/config): deprecated syntax for max-message-size; use file size syntax (such as in "100K") or "unlimited" instead.
>
> 2018-05-26 20:41:27 WARNING (line 82 of /etc/pmta/virtualhost.txt): "auto-cold-virtual-mta" deprecated; use explicitly defined cold Virtual MTAs instead.
>
> 2018-05-26 20:41:27 Startup error: Error in line 51 of /etc/pmta/config: Error in line 82 of /etc/pmta/virtualhost.txt: not a valid local IP address

I installed PMTA 4.5 on 5 different VPS and only this one not starting dunno what is wrong.
pmta/virtualhost.txt checked and ip is right.I know thease questions are stupid but i`m new with linux, thanks for help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The IP in line 82 is a public IP, try to change it to a private one like 192.168...